# Using Polymer 1.0 custom tags in a TSX Typescript file

Tags: typescript, polymer-1.0, tsx

I'm trying to use a Polymer custom tag in a Typescript .tsx file but it leads to a compile error:

```
declare module JSX {
    export interface IntrinsicElements {
        [anything: string]: any;
    }
}

let nativeTag = <br />;
let customTag = <paper-button />;
```

And the error is:

```
error TS2339: Property 'paper-button' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

Can anyone give a hint how to solve this problem?

```
$ tsc --version
Version 1.8.10
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is a bit outdated, but the documentation now suggests that you `declare namespace JSX` instead of `module`. On top of that, I had to wrap the whole namespace declaration in a `declare global` block. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11684